# Can't print external file content to cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to print the line of text from the external `txt` file which contains mentioned in the parameter to the argument `String`. 
But argument only works if i type text in the external file **manually**. 
If i **paste** text there, the method doesn't work. 
Is there anything i may missing?

Here's the method:

```
public void printLinesWhichContain(String word) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File (fileName), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        String line = reader.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(word)){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

And here's the program:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("src/textfile.txt");

printer.printLinesWhichContain("Väinämöinen");
System.out.println("-----");
printer.printLinesWhichContain("Frank Zappa");
System.out.println("-----");
printer.printLinesWhichContain("");
System.out.println("-----");
```

The output that I get is:

```
-----
-----
-----
```

Though, it must be:

```
Siinä vanha Väinämöinen
Sanoi vanha Väinämöinen
-----
-----
Siinä vanha Väinämöinen
katseleikse käänteleikse
Niin tuli kevätkäkönen
näki koivun kasvavaksi
Miksipä on tuo jätetty
koivahainen kaatamatta
Sanoi vanha Väinämöinen
```

Comment: It's definitely does not sound like a problem with Java code if it works for the same text typed manually. Check whatever you use for copying and pasting, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 

Turned out the problem was in encoding. 
When i changed default from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1  everything worked out.